# How to climb to specific parent element by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a small html code as blow :

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="comments">
    <div class="insider">
      <div class="text">
        some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am currently at `const ele = document.querySelector(".text")` and I wish to dynamically go up from the aforementioned element until I reach a class which has the name of "comments" and not farther than that.

How can I achieve this by vanilla JavaScript using `querySelector`?

Comment: "using `querySelector`":  why not using `parentElement` and `classList`?

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: you can use Element.closest(Selector). follow the article for more clarification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't move from child element to parent element using `document.querySelector()`. However, there are multiple ways to select the parent of an element.

You can use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method to get the closest ancestor element with the specified CSS selector.

```
document.querySelector(".text").closest('.comments');
```

`.closest()` method will  traverse the `.text` element and its ancestor elements (heading towards the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided CSS selector.

If the element on which `.closest()` method is called, matches the provided CSS selector, then that element is returned otherwise `.closest()` method returns the matching ancestor or `null` if not match is found.

Answer (score 3):

Use `closest()` is an builtIn method in JS.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector(".text")

let parent = elem.closest('.comments');  // specific parent

parent.classList.add("highlight"); // Do somthing ( Hightlight by Class )
```

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.highlight {
  border: 2px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
main
  <div class="comments">
  comments
    <div class="insider">
    insider
      <div class="text">
        some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```